# Shell argument truncated in half jenkinsfile shell error

Tags: shell, hadoop, jenkins-pipeline

I'm passing this value on jenkins file

```
ssh user@server1 'sudo salt server2.domain.name cmd.run "sudo su - userdem -c hadoop fs -copyFromLocal -f /local/userdem/copy_files/* /user/queryV2/common/nodes/"'
```

Error:
fs: opyFromLocal: command not found
ERROR: Minions returned with non-zero exit code

I tried with multiple compination of quotes and unquotes. It clearly sees it took only half of the argument as a variable and posting as error.

Comment: I don't know what _fs_ does, but perhaps it has an option `-c` and tries to run the command written as argument to this option.